# jQuery change function is not working in IE and FF when change selectable options with up/down keys

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this code `jQuery("#id").change(function (){
 // do something});`

where "id" is id of one  tag.
it works fine when I change selectable options with the mouse but if I change them using up-down keys, it works only in chrome, not in FF or IE.

Comment: I think I've read about this before. From what I remember, there's a difference in browsers in when they report the 'change' status (I think some report it when the control loses focus but not when just moving through options with the keyboard).

Comment: is there any hack for IE or FF ??

Comment: the change event fires on focus loss, if you want the change event to fire on arrows, you will have to add some keyup/keydown/keypress event handlers.

Comment: @Rizstien you can use a jquery `select` plugin like the one at http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-selectBox/ to see if that works for what you need